# Highlight or bold strings in a text file using python-docx?

Tags: python, text, highlight

I have a list of 'short strings', such as:

['MKWVTFISLLLLFSSAYSRGV', 'SSAYSRGVFRRDTHKSEIAH', 'KPKATEEQLKTVMENFVAFVDKCCA']

That I need to match to a 'long string' contained in a word file (BSA.docx) or .txt file (does not matter) such as:

> sp|P02769|ALBU_BOVIN Albumin OS=Bos taurus OX=9913 GN=ALB PE=1 SV=4
> MKWVTFISLLLLFSSAYSRGVFRRDTHKSEIAHRFKDLGEEHFKGLVLIAFSQYLQQCPFDEHVKLVNELTEFAKTCVADESHAGCEKSLHTLFGDELCKVASLRETYGDMADCCEKQEPERNECFLSHKDDSPDLPKLKPDPNTLCDEFKADEKKFWGKYLYEIARRHPYFYAPELLYYANKYNGVFQECCQAEDKGACLLPKIETMREKVLASSARQRLRCASIQKFGERALKAWSVARLSQKFPKAEFVEVTKLVTDLTKVHKECCHGDLLECADDRADLAKYICDNQDTISSKLKECCDKPLLEKSHCIAEVEKDAIPENLPPLTADFAEDKDVCKNYQEAKDAFLGSFLYEYSRRHPEYAVSVLLRLAKEYEATLEECCAKDDPHACYSTVFDKLKHLVDEPQNLIKQNCDQFEKLGEYGFQNALIVRYTRKVPQVSTPTLVEVSRSLGKVGTRCCTKPESERMPCTEDYLSLILNRLCVLHEKTPVSEKVTKCCTESLVNRRPCFSALTPDETYVPKAFDEKLFTFHADICTLPDTEKQIKKQTALVELLKHKPKATEEQLKTVMENFVAFVDKCCAADDKEACFAVEGPKLVVSTQTALA

What I would like to obtain is the following using python (in a terminal or in a jupyter notebook):

1. Highlight shorter strings matches in the long string. The highlight style is not important, it can be highlighted with a yellow marker or bolded, or underline, anything that jump to the eyes to see if there were matches or not.
2. Find the coverage of the long string as ((number of highlighted characters)/(total length of the long string))*100. Note the first line starting with ">>" of the long string is just an identifier and needs to be disregarded.

Here is my current code for the first task:

```py
from docx import Document

doc = Document('BSA.docx')

peptide_list = ['MKWVTFISLLLLFSSAYSRGV', 'SSAYSRGVFRRDTHKSEIAH', 'KPKATEEQLKTVMENFVAFVDKCCA']

def highlight_peptides(text, keywords):
    text = text.paragraphs[1].text
    replacement = "\033[91m" + "\\1" + "\033[39m"
    enter code here`text = re.sub("(" + "|".join(map(re.escape, keywords)) + ")", replacement, text, flags=re.I)
    

highlight_peptides(doc, peptide_list)
```

The problem is that the first two short strings in the list are overlapping and in the results only the first one is highlighted in red in the sequence.

See the first link below, that contains the output result I am obtaining.

[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVbQD.png)

See this second link to visualize my 'ideal' result.

[ideal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPFEK.png)

In the ideal I also included the second task of finding the sequence coverage. I am not sure how to count the colored or highlighted characters.

Comment: What do you mean by "highlight"? How will your output be rendered? Are you using this as a script in a terminal? Jupyter notebook? Web app? What have you tried so far? It's not too difficult to determine whether a string is a substring of another.

Comment: Hi ddejohn, thank you for the reply. I included additional explanations and the current code I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [third-party `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) to do an overlapping keyword search. Then, it is perhaps easiest to go through the matches in 2 passes: (1) storing the start and end positions of each highlighted segment and combining any that overlap:

```
import regex as re # important - not using the usual re module

def find_keywords(keywords, text):
    """ Return a list of positions where keywords start or end within the text. 
    Where keywords overlap, combine them. """
    pattern = "(" + "|".join(re.escape(word) for word in keywords) + ")"
    r = []
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, text, flags=re.I, overlapped=True):
        start, end = match.span()
        if not r or start > r[-1]: 
            r += [start, end]  # add new segment
        elif end > r[-1]:
            r[-1] = end        # combine with previous segment
    return r

positions = find_keywords(keywords, text)
```

Your 'keyword coverage' (percent highlighted) can be calculated as:

```
coverage = sum(positions[1::2]) - sum(positions[::2]) # sum of end positions - sum of start positions
percent_coverage = coverage * 100 / len(text)
```

Then (2) to add the formatting to the text, using the [`run` properties in `docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#run-objects):

```
import docx

def highlight_sections_docx(positions, text):
    """ Add characters to a text to highlight the segments indicated by
     a list of alternating start and end positions """
    document = docx.Document()
    p = document.add_paragraph()
    for i, (start, end) in enumerate(zip([None] + positions, positions + [None])):
        run = p.add_run(text[start:end])
        if i % 2:  # odd segments are highlighted
            run.bold = True   # or add other formatting - see https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#run-objects
    return document

doc = highlight_sections_docx(positions, text)
doc.save("my_word_doc.docx")
```

Alternatively, you could highlight the text in html, and then save this to a Word document using the [`htmldocx`](https://pypi.org/project/htmldocx/) package:

```
def highlight_sections(positions, text, start_highlight="<mark>", end_highlight="</mark>"):
    """ Add characters to a text to highlight the segments indicated by
     a list of alternating start and end positions """
    r = ""
    for i, (start, end) in enumerate(zip([None] + positions, positions + [None])):
        if i % 2:  # odd segments are highlighted
            r += start_highlight + text[start:end] + end_highlight
        else:      # even segments are not
            r += text[start:end]
    return r

from htmldocx import HtmlToDocx
s = highlight_sections(positions, text, start_highlight="<strong>", end_highlight="</strong>")
html = f"""<html><head></head><body><span style="width:100%; word-wrap:break-word; display:inline-block;">{s}</span></body></html>"""
HtmlToDocx().parse_html_string(html).save("my_word_doc.docx")
```

(`<mark>` would be a more appropriate html tag to use than `<strong>`, but unfortunately HtmlToDocx does not preserve any formatting of `<mark>`, and ignores CSS styles).

`highlight_sections` can also be used to output to the console:

```
print(highlight_sections(positions, text, start_highlight="\033[91m", end_highlight="\033[39m"))
```

... or to a Jupyter / IPython notebook:

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
s = highlight_sections(positions, text)
display(HTML(f"""<span style="width:100%; word-wrap:break-word; display:inline-block;">{s}</span>""")
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The first part works exactly as I should if I print it in a terminal. The keyword coverage is a little off though, I believe because while the formatting 'red color' can be visualized in the notebook if I count the characters it will interpret is as a string like including these formatting characters x1b[39m\x1b[39m. In addition if I try to save it in a text file it will also interpret these characters literally.

Comment: The keyword coverage calculation is based on the positions before any formatting is added, but could be affected by formatting that was already in the document.

Comment: You are right, it actually works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any way to save the formatting into a txt file or docx? Once I try it interprets the ASCII code as strings. One workaround I found is to modify the 'highlight_sections' function so that the 'odd segments' instead of being highlighted are returned in lowercase. if i % 2:  # odd segments are highlighted r += text[start:end].lower().

Comment: The formatting strings can be saved in, and later retrieved from, a text file, but most text editors won't apply the formatting and will instead change the `\033` as a special character. What is your preferred output exactly? If you're not sure or need multiple outputs, I suggest using HTML as this can easily be output to a Jupyter notebook or converted to a Word doc, or saved as-is.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happens. Ideally it would be a word file but HTML would also be ok. I am currently running it as a script in a terminal not on jupyter notebook. I assume I will need to change the ASCII characters to some HTML equivalent, such as <mark>?

Comment: I have edited showing various options for output

Comment: That is awesome, thank you!

Comment: Small update: while the code works with overlapping sequences, if among the short sequences there is a string fully contained within a previous one this will return an incorrect result. Example: ['MKWVTFISLLLLFSSAYSRGV', 'SSAYSRGVFRRDTHKSEIAH', 'KPKATEEQLKTVMENFVAFVDKCCA', 'FRRDTHKS']. As a result of the presence of the fourth sequence the character EIAH will not be highlighted. Any idea how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: thanks, I have edited `find_keywords` to fix this, by adding the condition `elif end > r[-1]:`, so that the position is only updated if the end of the current match is to the right of the end of the previous match.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for updating it.